# File not found: /Users/ChristopherSchreuder/eclipse-workspace1/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.debug.core

Tags: javascript

I may have accidentally deleted something somewhere and now when I try to run a program, it says

> File not found: /Users/ChristopherSchreuder/eclipse-workspace1/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.debug.core

I have deleted and reinstalled Eclipse but this didn’t solve the problem. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse installation is usually different than the workspace.

You seem to have deleted files from the workspace.

I would suggest you create a new workspace in a different location, then copy whatever files/projects needed from the old workspace location `/Users/ChristopherSchreuder/eclipse-workspace1` to the new one